# Integrating facial recongition and emotion recognition using vgg16 model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am working on two separate systems; facial recognition and emotion recognition systems using VGG16 (pre-trained model). I implement these systems using Google collabs.

The facial recognition system using the VGG16 model can recognize the faces of the participants and the emotion recognition system can recognize the emotions of the participants.
These links were used as guidelines to implement the [facial recognition system](https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/build-your-own-facial-recognition-system-to-work-even-with-a-face-mask-b240539222f6) and [emotion recognition system](https://github.com/akmadan/Emotion_Detection_CNN/blob/main/main.py). I want to integrate both systems so they can function as one system so, for example, I want the system to be able to recognize the face and the emotions of the participants using the VGG16 model but I don't know how to integrate these systems I have searched on google but I can't find any resource or any documentation that talks about their integration.

I know I am supposed to talk about coding issues on here, but I don't know any other community that can help apart from this community. Any explanation or references will be greatly appreciated as that will make me proceed further.